# vector cannot be initialized by {}

Tags: c++, vector

Hi I am a newbie in C++ and I just cannot initialize a vector using {}, even if the code is copied with a book. For example, when I do these

```
vector <string> articles {"a", "an", "the"};
```

And

```
vector <string> articles = {"a", "an", "the"};
```

I got these  error message respectively:

```
Error: expected a ";"
```

And

```
Error: initialization with "{...}" is not allowed for object of type "std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string>>"
```

Would anyone help me out? I believe it should be a simple mistake that I couldn't find out.

Comment: Which compiler and which options are you compiling with?

Comment: Do you mean this?: vector<char*> articles = {"a", "an", "the"};

Comment: sorry chris, but how to check what kind of compiler I am using? I am so new. I am using microsoft visual studio 2012 and have not change any settings regarding the compiler...

Comment: @user2415924, Okay, so that doesn't support initializer lists unless you use the CTP and even that doesn't have library support for them. The easiest option is to use an array and then initialize the vector with two iterators over that array.

Comment: This does not work also 
vector<string> articles = {"a", "an", "the"};

Comment: this initialization is part of c++11 , check if your compiler supports  c++11.

Answer (score 2):

`uniform initialization` is introduced since C++11, You should use a recent compiler that supports this new feature.

If your compiler does not support this feature, you may try the following:

```
string arrOfString[3] =  {"a", "an", "the"};
vector<string> articles(arrOfString, arrOfString +3);
```

**EDIT**:

with MSVC11, you can do (by courtesy of @chris):

```
string arrOfString[3] =  {"a", "an", "the"};
vector<string> articles(std::begin(arrOfString), std::end(arrOfString));
```

Comment: With MSVC11, I'd use `std::begin(arrOfString), std::end(arrOfString)`.

Comment: @chris ah, that's nicer if MSVC11 supports it. I did not know this before, thank you. will update the post.

Comment: thank you! Could you please let me know how to download a recent compiler?

Comment: @user2415924 If you are using UNIX/LINUX, you may want to take a look at gcc: http://gcc.gnu.org/

Comment: Im using windows MSVC 2012. I have downloaded a 2012 CTP but it still doesnt work...

Comment: @user2415924 I am sorry since I don't know how to deal with MSVC, it may still do not have support even with CTP. I am using gcc.

Comment: Thank you for much for all your replies!!